# PHP replace parameters

Tags: php, replace

i got a string for example: `"Some string $1 and something else $2"`.
I need to replace $1, $2 with values from array:

```
$1 -> myarry['parameters'][1]['value']    
$2 -> myarry['parameters'][2]['value']
```

How can i do this?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: RTFM please, `str_replace`, `strtr`.

Comment: I would suggest the str_replace function, documented with many examples here: http://us2.php.net/str_replace

Comment: sprintf to the rescue...

Comment: You literally want to replace `$1` (being a string, not a variable) with the value from your array?

Comment: `$1 = myarry['parameters'][1]['value'];`  ??

Comment: I have seen it but i don't know how to "take" number from first string and use it for array

Comment: @putvande yes, its a string not a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
preg_replace_callback('/\$(\d+)/', function($match) use ($myarray) {
    $i = $match[1];
    return $myarray['parameters'][$i]['value'];
}, $string);
```

You might want to search for template libraries.

Comment: Great! Thank you very match ! I had to change $i = substr($match, 1); to $i = substr($match[0], 1); and it works!

Comment: I forgot that `$match` is an array that includes all the capture groups. I simplified it so `substr` isn't needed.

Comment: I think substr is needed becouse we need 1 not $1

Comment: But the `$` is outside the capture group that I just added in the update.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$string = "Some string $1 and something else $2";
$search = array("$1", "$2");
$replace = array($myarray['parameters'][1]['value'], $myarray['parameters'][2]['value']);
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: But what if i have for example $321 ? a bit to much to copy

Comment: Then you do the same for `$321`.